# Formatting/Styling of Stack Exchange sites is not displaying

Tags: support, design, google-chrome

**Background:**

When trying to access any site other than Meta Stack Exchange, the pages sometimes load without any styling or formatting when loaded in Chrome. It appears to be the HTML without the CSS styling, images, etc.

Once this happens for one site, it affects all non-Meta sites (that I have checked), though it does not consistently happen, e.g., when I first load up Chrome as the computer starts I may or may not, and randomly through-out the day it may start happening.

I can rectify this issue by loading any non-Meta page in IE, which then allows the styling/formatting to work in Chrome (after a reload (f5)... not just a cache reload (ctrl+f5)).

---

**My system:**

Operating on a work laptop with docking station. Not sure of our ISP, offhand. I do have the following information:

- OS:  Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601)
- Chrome:  Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)

  - Extensions:  Click & Clean, F*ck Overlays, Privacy badger, uBlock origin (3), reddit enhancement suite, and Empty new page tab.
  - I have tried running Chrome with no extensions and the issue has occurred in this scenario.
  - "Browser is managed by organization."
- IE:  Version 11.0.9600.19301

  - No addons

---

**Issue:**

Since I have a workaround via IE, the overarching issue is "why does this happen randomly for Chrome."  If it happened consistently, you can work with that...

---

**Question:**

Has anyone experienced this issue before, and if so, how did you resolve?

Comment: PS, I have no idea what makes Meta different from the other sites that it does not seem affected.